# Container Loading Problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, heuristics, metaheuristics, excel

I'd like to optimize the loading problem in first-mile delivery that maximize the occupancy of the truck. The main question to be answered is this: with the given truck, would this list of items fit or not fit? If fit, can we know the visualization of the items in the trucks? If not, can we know the items that are not carried?

My early research is that this problem is like the container loading problem (clp). The items are in cartoon, and I just want to know for each truck. The items are weakly heterogeneous but they tend to have a lot in number of quantity (since it is first mile delivery).
Any advice about how to solve this? I would want to stay as close as possible with Excel and Python.

Comment: How many dimensions are considered?

Comment: @Kuifje 3D would be nice, but I'm open to any inputs

Answer (score 3):

As a free Excel plugin to solve a 3D packing problem and already with the visualization, the Vehicle Routing and Logistics Optimization within EURO, [VeRoLog](https://www.euro-online.org/websites/verolog/clp-spreadsheet-solver-2/), has a material that may help to solve such a problem.

Another solver may be [PackingSolver](https://github.com/fontanf/packingsolver) which was developed by *Dr. Florian Fontan* (in the community @fontanf). It would be interesting to solve 2D and also 3D packing problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering, curious to see if it can solve with more than 2000+ number of items to pack into one container (they are weakly heterogeneous)

Comment: Indeed, that's the kind of problem that my package could solve. Still, 2000 items in one container is a lot. Depending on the characteristics of the instances, it might require to design a dedicated algorithm